# Why does my BeginInvoke run synchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, begininvoke

I have created a WCF application and in multiple places I am using BeginInvoke to run methods asynchronously. In some places it is asynchronous and in others it runs synchronously. Because the system is quite complicated I was hoping to just throw this high level question out there in the hope that someone knows a reason that BeginInvoke would be forced into synchronous running.

Possible reasons I have considered and believe are not the cause:

- I ran out of ThreadPool Threads - I think at peak I use less than 20 threads.
- I use locking across those threads stopping their concurrent executions - No synchronization is employed since each call is to a method on a separate WCF ServiceHost
- A parent asynchronous method (which definitely is running asynchronously) calls many child BeginInvokes and you can't nest asynchronous invocations - I don't think that is a limitation
- The parent asynchronous method is itself part of a WCF ServiceHost that is InstanceContextMode.PerSession and there is some limitation on it nesting asynchronous calls - Again, I don't think so, but FYI
- Each child being called is a (different to the parent) WCF ServiceHost whose method I am calling is an instance of the same ServiceType and is run as InstanceContextMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode.Single. - Does that in some way impact the calling routine from running those asynchronously (I don't see why it would, but just in case)

Any ideas/solutions are much appreciated

Comment: Can you tell us how you came to the conclusion that they are running synchronously? Perhaps the calling thread is being blocked while they are completing?

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is a "broad name". Which BeginInvoke you are referring to? `Control.BeginInvoke`? `Delegate.BeginInvoke`? `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? or a different one? Next question - what threads are used, I mean, which thread(s) are invoking it and which threads are the targets there? any synchronization contexts used?custom threads with message pumps or without? Tasks or TPL library? Custom dispatchers or schedulers? (....) actually, trimming and showing the code may be faster than quizzing you for details..

Comment: Ron Beyer: The code doesn't block, it uses the IsCompleted check in a loop to see when to call EndInvoke. I know it is synchronous because I interrogate the status of the calls every 10 seconds and I can see from the logs that those interrogations all occur before my code is able to check the first IsCompleted status

Comment: @pogpogoSE - Please use the `@` symbol for notifications. I don't think your method of checking proves that the calls are synchronous. Can you please edit the question and post your code? Then we can actually run your code and check for ourselves.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl You are right, I should have clarified it is Delegate.BeginInvoke. No synchronization contexts as stated. Trimming the code would be tricky. There is a lot of it. It is a distributed Data Engine that runs across multiple physical machines. It might be easier to try and replicate the issue under simplified circumstances. Or I could try and strip the relevant parts of the code out, but it may take some time

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks for the @ tip! As I just replied regarding the code,it would be complicated to explain how to run it and provide data to load into the Data Engine etc. That is why I went for the "conceptual" approach. Regarding your thought that it is not running synchronously, I think that my check does strongly suggest that it is synchronous. Each call starts in turn and in the order it was called and between those calls I sometimes see two log entries of my interrogation/ping showing that 10 seconds has elapsed for an invocation that should be milliseconds at most

Comment: @pogpogoSE - You really should provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example. Then we can answer you. The "conceptual" approach is not very helpful and you'll turn away many smart people using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to reference this quote regarding `Delegate.BeginInvoke` from Joe Duffy, in his book Concurrent Programming on Windows:

> All delegate types, by convention offer a BeginInvoke and EndInvoke method alongside the ordinary synchronous Invoke method. While this is a nice programming model feature, you should stay away from them wherever possible. The implementation uses remoting infrastructure which imposes a sizable overhead to asynchronous invocation. Queue work to the thread pool directly is often a better approach, though that means you have to co-ordinate the rendezvous logic yourself.

I've done my own tests before, and the overhead can amount to many seconds when using these frequently. Perhaps this is not an answer to your question - because one would be almost impossible I think without seeing and debugging the code. This is rather a suggestion that you should take another look at your approach. Perhaps by queuing work to the ThreadPool directly, or using TPL (Task's / async&await).

If you're still set in finding the problem with the current code instead of revising it for a better strategy, and you still want help, you should find a way to reproduce your symptoms (that it is running synchronously) and provide code proving this.

Comment: I know having code is ideal, but I was really hoping there was something that other people had come across that could be causing it. If not then a different approach is required. The overhead of invocation seems pretty small since I run the same code on a fast running method before the code I have described and it is very quick. The purpose of this sequence is to provide a synchronized data refresh First step prepares for it and the second step executes as long as none of the services found any issues. Preparation is very fast.